# Personalization strings as AMPscript variables

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

This may seem like a seemingly simple thing to do, but I haven't had a need to tinker with AMPscript until recently. I'm merely looking up a value in a Data Extension based on a Subscriber ID. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
%%[ VAR @account_id SET @account_id = %%subscriberid%% ]%%
<p>Your score is %%=Lookup("Sample Quiz","A1","account_id",@account_id)=%%</p>
```

Turns out that my personalization string in a variable is invalid AMPscript, which doesn't surprise me. If I hardcode a variable value it works fine:

```
%%[ VAR @account_id SET @account_id = 1 ]%%
<p>Your score is %%=Lookup("Sample Quiz","A1","account_id",@account_id)=%%</p>
```

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the [AttributeValue()](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) function when dealing with personalization strings.  It'll return an empty string if it doesn't exist:

**Data Extension**

```
SubscriberID | EmailAddress
-------------+------------------------
238535       | test@example.com
```

**Code**

```
%%[
  VAR @account_id
  SET @account_id = AttributeValue("subscriberid")
  set @emailAddress = iif(not empty(@account_id),lookup("AMPScriptTest","EmailAddress","SubscriberID",@account_id),"not found")
]%%
<br>account_id: %%=v(@account_id)=%%
<br>Your emailAddress is: %%=v(@emailAddress)=%%
```

**Output (via Email Send Preview)**

```
account_id: 238535 
Your emailAddress is: test@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Within an AMPScript block you do not need additional "%%" around the personalization strings.  It will work like the below:

```
%%[ VAR @account_id SET @account_id = subscriberid ]%%
<p>Your score is %%=Lookup("Sample Quiz","A1","account_id",@account_id)=%%</p>
```

Similarly you could accomplish the same thing with just the below:

```
   <p>Your score is %%=Lookup("Sample Quiz","A1","account_id",subscriberid)=%%</p>
```